# I have a table where customer ID are being duplicated because of their reactivation date. I need to pivot the reactivation date per CustomerID

Tags: sql-server

I have a following table

[image]

I need to pivot the table and have it like the table below:

[image]

How can I have the unique customer ID in a column and all the reactivation dates pivoted like in the above picture?

Comment: which database (and version) is being used - this is vital as the pivot capability/syntax differs between db vendors. Always use a tag to indicate the database e.g. MySQL, Oracle etc.

Comment: Hi Paul, sorry for the delayed response. I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Thank you

Comment: I edited the tags accordingly, please use tags not comments for such vital information, it really is important to how the site works. You didn't mention what version,  this really can matter if running an old version as solutions options may be limited.

Comment: There is a larger data modelling question here. Do you propose to dynamically add columns forever? It's a more sensible data model to move reactivation date out into a different transactional table, and optioanly store the only date of most interest (most recent reactivation) as an attribute of customer in this table

Comment: another tip for questions here. Don't use images of data. Instead just create a table of values using text. This allow people to create small test cases to test and demonstrate their solutions. Ultimately this helps you to get a valid answer faster. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
or  
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

To attribute a numeric sequence to the reactivation dates, use `row_number() over()` and then you can pivot that sequence from rows to columns:

```
select 
      customer_id
    , activation_date
    , [1] as reactivation_dt_1
    , [2] as reactivation_dt_2
    , [3] as reactivation_dt_3
    , [4] as reactivation_dt_4
from (
     select
            customer_id, activation_date, reactivation_date
          , row_number() over(partition by customer_id 
                              order by reactivation_date ASC) as pivcol
     from mytable
     ) as d
pivot (
       max(reactivation_date)
       for pivcol in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
      ) as p
order by  
      customer_id
```

**result**

```
+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| customer_id | activation_date | reactivation_dt_1 | reactivation_dt_2 | reactivation_dt_3 | reactivation_dt_4 |
+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|           1 | 2010-01-01      | 2012-02-01        | 2015-03-01        | 2017-07-01        | 2022-07-01        |
|           2 | 2011-12-03      | 2013-05-01        | 2014-08-10        | 2015-12-09        |                   |
+-------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e19d83a8f17bfece71d9b779626f7c1)*